# Qgis Text/Annotation as layer

Tags: qgis, cartography, annotation

Is there a way to add text/annotation to my map in QGIS as a layer?
I have a map of vegetation types an point data the text (field names/flurnamne) should be between these two layers. It there must not be a background or box around it and should not cover the points. It would be ideal if I could arrange the text on a path or line as the shortest name must stand for the largest area.

Is there a way to add annotation just a text, no box, background or point?

At the moment I just added text in print composer and set transparency, but results are not very satisfying

EDIT: The text should be under the points. I have a map with the vegetation types and the point data and want to add the fieldnames/flurnamen of certain area. It would ideal if spacing etc. could be adjusted so that the text covers the whole area, e.g. name_1 in on the line.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify: Do you mean that you want to draw the points over the labels, i.e. points should cover labels where necessary? Maybe you could add a sketch?

Comment: The description contradicts the sketch since the "Name_2" label overlaps the underlying points. But it seems like you have already found a solution that works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Add a new line feature, set transparancy to 100% and lable this line.

It seems to produce the a good result, as letter spacing & transparancy can be adjusted.

Comment: There’s a drawback to this if you export the map as vectors, such as to a PDF: the lines will still output, they’ll just be transparent. (This can be verified by opening the PDF in Illustrator or other vector program.) This is s problem if you have a lot of features, as the size of the output would increase considerably.

Comment: Sorry, posted too soon... Just set the layer’s symbology type to **No symbols** (or something like that; QGIS isn’t in front of me at the moment).